# I can't open Windows Update Minitool anymore

Tags: windows-update, windows-10-v1803

I have a Asus K73S laptop with Windows 10 Home v.1803.

I have been using [Windows Update MiniTool](https://win10.guru/toolkit-item-windows-update-minitool-wumt/) for some time now, without problems.

Now, I can't open it.  In the window that appears, I get the following message (translated to English):

> To continue, enter a username and a password as an administrator

But I can't enter username and password in the window.

**Diagnostics** (I am collecting additional information and will add to this as it is available):

- WUMT has not required administrator privileges in the past.  I also run it on another computer, and do not get this prompt there.  So the issue seems to be specific to this installation.
- I tried to uninstall and reinstall WUMT, but the problem is always the same, which suggests that the symptom is not caused by WUMT being corrupted.
- I tried launching WUMT from an elevated command prompt ("Run as administrator" from the right-click context menu on cmd.exe).  Under those circumstances, I should not be seeing a request for credentials.  However, I still get that window, and it still fails.
- In case it is relevant, I am the only user of this computer and never created a user or password.  The command prompt shows what is apparently a default username of "User" (command prompt text is `C:\User\User>`).

Can someone guide me to solve this problem?  Please suggest any diagnostics that might be helpful.

Comment: Does it work if "run as admin"?

Comment: This is not an official Microsoft app. Have you spoken with or attempted to contact the developer or followed their recommendations for the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the GabrielaGarcia question, I realized that I could not become an administrator and I could not even update any application, because the prompt always appeared asking to enter the username and password as an administrator.  The administrator account was missing, and nothing would work that required elevated privileges. Now I have reinstalled Windows 10 with the latest version (1903) and everything works